# What are the limitations of Styled Components in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

There is a full feature set with Styled Components when developing in React.  It seems you don't get the full experience in react-native.

These limitation aren't really specified anywhere. What are the exact limitations?

<sub>I know selectors is one of them.</sub>

Comment: A little bit curious...How do you know you're not getting full experience in React-Native if you don't know the limitation? To me, limitations to styled components are same as limitation to React Native, that you have to sometimes writes style for both platforms separately. But I don't feel like there's something unachievable standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dug around on this for a while and found a good response in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2893#issuecomment-559182228). @Andus in the comments is correct. Styled Components simply works within the bounds of React Native flavored CSS.

> There are no pseudo elements in React Native  Similarly you won't be able to use:
>
> - Any unsupported positioning
> - Some transforms don't have transformations afaik
> - Child / Children / Sibling selectors
> - Media queries or other at rules
>
> Sorry about that! React Native is very focused on their style system, in the sense that they don't support full CSS but only CSS-like StyleSheets, so all that is done on RN in styled-components is some thin conversions to StyleSheets.